# The method 'showAdaptiveDialog' isn't defined for the class '_LinkedProvidersRowState'

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

In Flutter I was trying this codelab by Google: [link](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#3)

When I import these two files in my code:

```
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider;
```

I don't even use anything from the imports as of yet.
I get the following error on compilation:

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.10.0/lib/src/screens/profile_screen.dart:215:25: Error: The method 'showAdaptiveDialog' isn't defined for the class '_LinkedProvidersRowState'.
 - '_LinkedProvidersRowState' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/screens/profile_screen.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.10.0/lib/src/screens/profile_screen.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showAdaptiveDialog'.
      confirmed = await showAdaptiveDialog<bool?>(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

Could you kindly help?

I tried running it with the import & without the import. The error occurs only during the import.

Comment: try "flutter clean" and then "Flutter pub get"... and hope you added the packages..

Comment: Kindly share the versions of the packages you are using from your pubspec.yaml file.